# JAVA: JDBC Connection by URL Aurora(mysql) aws

Tags: java, application-server

i want to connect to a D by an URL i got to make the conections.

```
static Connection cnx = null;
public static Connection obtener() throws SQLException{
    if (cnx == null) {
        try {
            cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://combis.cpgtn4fi7t5t.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/am_myDataBase", "user", "pass");
        }catch (SQLException es) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            throw new SQLException(es);
        }
    }
    return cnx;
}
```

and i can not get the connection. Is it well written the URL?
got this Error:

java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://combis.cpgtn4fi7t5t.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/am_myDataBase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to do two things here that are:-

1.Load the mysql driver class.

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

2.Change the connection url like this-

```
 jdbc:mysql://combis.cpgtn4fi7t5t.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/am_myDataBase?useSSL=false
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: Still having  the problem:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)

Comment: have you added mysql_connector jar file in your build class Path? if not , here is link for download http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm

Comment: damn me, yes! was missing the jar

Comment: connected successfully? @cristiamalbertogiranocorber

Comment: Yes, Thanks u so much

Answer (score 0):

Use below to load driver before getting connection

```
    Class.forName("<driver class name>");
```

Comment: For java 1.7 up it is not necesary, but i tested and  got a same problem.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at lambda.BreakCode.main(BreakCode.java:58)